# Questions similar to Wason Selection Task

Tags: proofs, exercises, discrete-math

The Wason Selection Task (described by Pete Clark [here](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/412/117)) is a great problem for getting students to grapple with all of the intricacies of logical implication.

I will be teaching a discrete mathematics course for the first time in about a month, and I would love to have a sizable repository of similar questions.

Does anyone have a link to a big list of similar questions?  If not, I am happy to hear your ideas about similar problems which might stimulate a similar amount of thinking about the other logical operators.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but as a comment: How does one formalize the sentence "[I'll go unless it rains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osTPP.jpg)"? I learned this example from Norton Starr - who had discussed it with Susanna Epp [who wrote a nice discrete math textbook...] enough for her to bring it up in colloquium talks many years later.

Comment: You might take a look at the LSAT (practice tests or prep books like Kaplan or Princeton Review).  There are a lot of truth tables and reasoning questions (at least used to be).  Also, the pre 2002 GRE had a section called Analytical that was very similar.  If you can get old tests (or old prep books), you will have lots of these little problems.  Also the prep books have some good advice on how to use diagrams and tables to sort out the wording and solve the problems.