# A better example of a logical implication

Tags: mathematical-pedagogy, logic

(Updated)

An example of a logical (material) implication that is commonly  used  is: "If it is raining outside, then the ground is wet." The problem with this example is that it could be seen as a *causal* relationship, i.e. that rain *cause*s the ground to be wet, possibly leading to confusion conflating implication and causality--a common mistake among beginners.

**Q:** Might a better example not be: "If it is raining, then it is cloudy?"

I think (hope?) that it is common knowledge that rain does not *cause* cloudiness. This alternative example means only that, at the moment, it is not both raining and not cloudy.

$~~~~~~~~Raining \to Cloudy ~~\equiv~~ \neg [Raining \land \neg Cloudy]$

More generally, for any logical propositions $A$ and $B$:

$~~~~~~~~A \to B ~~ \equiv~~ \neg [ A ~\land \neg B] $

This interpretation can be easily seen to be consistent with the usual truth table for logical implication:

[image]

The rule of detachment (*modus ponens*) can also be easily seen to hold by this interpretation. When both $A$ and $A\to B$ are true (only on line 1), then $B$ must also be true.

---

From my comment below: Care must be taken to avoid examples of relations that may be construed as causal. Ideally, both antecedent and consequent should be stated in the present tense.

Mathematical statements, e.g. *y*=*x*+1, should be thought of as being stated in the *present tense*.

Comment: In Mathematics, the implication-refers-to-causation myth is overstated; the real issue with using the first example is simply that it is a propositional-logic (PL) example which does not actually correspond to typical maths statements. When students raise questions about implications, it is invariably about false antecedents or due to them forgetting that something like `Px⟹Qx` is implicitly universally quantified (`∀x`), that is, not realising that mathematical implications are predicate-logic implications rather than the PL implications they've just encountered in their Discrete Maths class.

Comment: [Rain without clouds?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/rain-without-clouds). — If the students know calculus, which mine do, then I use "If $f$ is differentiable at $0$, then it is continuous at $0$." I have the students try to generate examples of that show all (possible) combinations T/F. Things seem clearer in mathematics than in nature/society. — I don't see an actual question being posed above. I suppose you're asking for reactions to your opinion, or for others to share their experiences.

Comment: You might find this question helpful: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/353/how-to-teach-logical-implication/24369#24369

Comment: Are you asking for more examples?  I didn't see a question in the post.

Comment: [continuing] That these toy examples are merely isolated conditionals that aren't about *logical* implication/entailment (that is, a conditional being true regardless of the meaning of the words/symbols used) is another reason they feel artificial/contrived. What I mean is that 1) the truth of the raining-cloudy implication depends on the particular interpretation/context, and that 2) it is not being specified as part of an argument (as a premise/conclusion) and thus not being used for inference/deduction. $\quad$ [4 types of 'imply'](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4652026/21813).

Comment: @ryang I think we can agree that there is no built-in notion of causation or the passage of time in mathematics. The first example suggests causation. My rain-and-clouds example does not suggest a causational relation. Neither does it suggest anything about the future or past, only the present. There also no suggestion of examining more than one case (with quantifiers, etc.). It seems to me that it is a better example of mathematical implication.

Comment: @StevenGubkin I am asking for comments on my contention that my rain-and-clouds example is a "better example" than one often given in the literature.

Comment: I'll rephrase. Indeed, classical logic and mathematics are tense-agnostic; however, the likely actual issue with Toy Example 1, with regards to mathematics, is not that it suggests causation, but that its truth/falsity—like that of Toy Example 2—is merely [synthetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4652026/21813) (whereas mathematical implications are analytic truths). Neither of them are *logical* implications either, since the truth value of each depends simply on the predefined context/situation/interpretation. (Logical implications are stronger than mathematical implications.)

Comment: @ryang "Toy examples," as you call them, can be useful to introduce abstract concepts, but they must chosen carefully. Since implication is so often confused with causality, I think it is important in this case to not inadvertently introduce a possibly causal relationship as in example #1. It also easier to grasp that it is raining than f is differentiable at 0.

Comment: Maybe philosophy.stackexchange.com is a better place for this question? This  seems to be more about the relationship between natural language, causality, and implication, not about mathematics. See for example [this answer.](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/24191)

Comment: @JustinHancock It is a matter of pedagogy. There seems to be much confusion about logical implication among students. It occurred to me that some of the examples used by various authors may contribute to it. Care must be taken to avoid examples of relations that may be construed as causal. Ideally, they should use statements in the present tense for both antecedent and consequents.

Comment: Who are the students that you’re referring to? Students in a formal logic course, or students in an intro to proofs course, or some other group of students? Different examples are suited to different pedagogical contexts.

Comment: @JustinHancock I had in mind the intro to proof course, but it could be used in either course. It could even be used by high-school students trying to understand the truth table for logical implication.

Comment: Keith Devlin's book "Introduction to Mathematical Thinking" transformed and clarified my understanding on this. Section 2.3 he explains implication = conditional + causation. Mathematical proof is only interested in the conditional and there needs to be no causative connection between the terms for the conditional statement to be true. The problems in understanding arise from the use of the expression "A implies B" in mathematics brings the  "baggage" of causation which is not relevant nor useful in a mathematical situation. Devlin explains it far more clearly.

Answer (score 4):

My answer is a bit of a frame challenge to the question (and to the part of [Stephen Gubkin's answer](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/26313/16250) where real world examples are said to be poorly suited for teaching purposes).

I agree that *"If it is raining, then it is cloudy"* might be advantageous since, in contrast to *"If it is raining outside, then the ground is wet"*, it does not suggest any relation to causality.

However, I think both examples are actually formulated in a way that makes it difficult to understand the point of implications. For me the problem, though, is not that they are "real-world" examples, but something else: the wording does not make it clear that the involved propositions in both implications depend on a free variable - but this is actually the point why implications are so useful in mathematics.

Here's what I mean by this in detail:

**Implication between propositions without variables and with known truth values**

An implication between two propositions whose truth values are fixed and known appears to be intuitively odd, no matter whether in mathematics or in real life.
Consider the following examples, the first of which I copied from Stephen Gubkin's answer:

- If the moon is made of cheese, then I am the Pope.
- If the moon is not made of cheese, then water is wet.
- If $5 = 11-10$, then $3 = 2+9$.
- If $5 \not= 11-10$, then $2+2=4$.

I've been working in mathematics for about 10 years now and still don't have any good intuition for any of those four examples. Actually, I find the last two just as non-telling as the first two.
The intuitive problem with all four implications is that the truth values of their premises and conclusions are fixed and known - they do not depend on any free variable.

**Propositions that depend on a variable:**

Implications make much more sense intuitively if one uses them for propositions that depend on a variable and whose truth values can change depending on that variable.
Examples:

- If an integer $n$ is divisible by $4$, then it is also divisible by $2$.
- If a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, then it is continuous.
- If $H$ is a subgroup of a finite group $G$, then the cardinality of $H$ divides the cardinality of $G$.
- If a Banach space $E$ is infinite-dimensional, then every algebraic basis of $E$ is uncountable.

The same works for "real-life" examples: as soon as they depend on a variable which might make the involved proposition true or false, things get much more intuitive:

- If a planet supports the evolution of Carbon-based life, then there exists liquid water on it.

  Or, if you want to make the variable more explicit:

  If a planet $P$ supports the evolution of Carbon-based life, then there exists liquid water on $P$.
- If it's raining on a street $S$, then $S$ gets wet.
- If it's raining at a place $P$, then there are clouds over $P$.

The last two example are the ones from the question on which I commented at the beginning of this answer.
The way I worded them now is, of course more technical - but I think this is actually an advantage for the following reasons:

1. It makes it very clear and explicit that there is, in a sense, "uncertain knowledge" involved in the implication and that the uncertainty stems from the fact that we do not know the value of the variable.
   This illustrates the very point of a (true) implication: while there might be uncertainty about the truth values of the premise and the conclusion, the implication tells us that at least a certain relation between them is always true.
2. In such an example one can easily illustrate all four combinations of truth values of the premise and the conclusion by inserting different values for the variable.
3. Implications between propositions that depend on a variable is actually how implications occur in mathematical results, so those examples are a good way to prepare the students for this.
4. The transition from everyday language to more formal logical expressions can be smoothened this way:
   We may start with the sentence "When it rains, it is cloudy", then let the students notice that there is an implicit assumption in this sentence that we talk about a specific location (since the whether is not the same everywhere), and then make this assumption explicit by denoting the location by a variable.

Comment: I like this approach for a math course since, as [@ryang says](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/26312/a-better-example-of-a-logical-implication#comment69548_26312), we are always working with quantified statements in mathematics. Velleman introduces the conditional this way in *How to Prove It*. But what about a course where students are working with propositional logic?

Comment: The usual truth table for IMPLIES applies to both propositional and predicate logic. As to the "intuition" behind it, each line of this table can be effectively derived from "first principles." See Line 1: A & B => [A => B] http://www.dcproof.com/ImpliesLine1.html Line 2: A & ~B => ~[A => B] http://www.dcproof.com/ImpliesLine2.html Lines 3-4: ~A => [A => B] http://www.dcproof.com/ImpliesLines3-4.html Whether or not A and B make reference to variables is irrelevant.

Comment: @DanChristensen: I'm not sure I follow your reasoning: the fact that something can be derived from first principles does not make this something automatically intuitive - in particular not for students who see it for the first time. From a formal point of view it is of course irrelevant if A and B depend an variables. For understanding how the definition of implication relates to the intuition of implications that one gets from everyday language though, it is very instructive to focus on examples where $A$ and $B$ depend on variables.

Comment: @JustinHancock: Good question. What are courses, though, where students really only work with propositional logic? The vast majority of mathematical theorems contains somekind of quantification - it's just often not made explicit. So one could try to use the same approach and not to discuss the quantification explicitly - as one probably does anyway with all the theorems that are discussed in such a course (that's also why I've phrased the examples in the answer in a slightly vague way that doesn't use quantifiers).

Comment: If students have sufficient mastery of the methods of proof, these proofs should be intuitively reassuring. If not, you can only present the truth table or (A => B) = ~(A & ~B) as The Definition of IMPLIES, emphasizing that A and B must unambiguously either true or false in the present. You can say, "The proofs are beyond the scope of this course, etc." Also if students have not thoroughly mastered propositional logic, it is pointless to go on to predicate logic. Again, the same truth table will apply for both.

Comment: @DanChristensen: If you assume that the students find implications intuitive anyway (due to "sufficient mastery of the methods of proof" or for whatever reason), then what is the point of your question?

Comment: @JochenGlueck (1) As soon as students know how to introduce and discharge a premise, how to join two statements with AND and how to remove double negations, they can prove, for example, that ~A => (A =>B) (lines 3-4 of the truth table). A nice little 8-line exercise! (2) The point of the question is to be careful when introducing examples for logical implication, i.e.. avoid relations that could be construed as causal, and stick to the present tense for the antecedent and consequent.

Comment: For time-dependent propositions (e.g. predictions about the future), I think you will need predicate logic.

Comment: @DanChristensen: Well, if you think that those purely formal arguments will give the students sufficient intuition for implications, then why would you give real-world examples at all? And what kind of students will get a good feeling for implications from purely abstract considerations, but are at risk of confusing implication with causation? I'm really having difficulties to understand what concrete situation in teaching you have in mind. Could you maybe specify which kind of course and which kind of students you are thinking of?

Comment: Each of the four examples you list does have a natural justification under the interpretation "I can prove q given a proof of p".  Namely: if q is true you can give a proof of it whether or not p has a proof.  If p is false then you can give a proof of q by explosion irrespective of the truth of q.  If p is true and q is false you cannot give a proof of q starting from a proof of p.

Comment: @StevenGubkin: Yes, I agree. The part of your answer with which I don't really agree is the claim that real world examples were poorly suited for implications in most cases. I think this mainly happens when there's no variable over which one can quantify (e.g. you're "moon made of cheese" examples). I'll edit to clarify that I'm referring to this specific part of your answer.

Comment: @JochenGlueck I disagree that *all* examples of "useful" implications are of the form $\forall x:  P(x) \implies Q(x)$.  For instance, we might usefully prove a theorem of the form "If there exists a largest twin prime $p$, then [some inequality is true]."  Here both the antecedent and consequent are both "plain facts", but the theorem could still be useful as part of an attack on the twin prime conjecture.  We still prove the theorem the same as always:  assuming we have a proof that an integer $p$ is the largest twin prime, we attempt to prove the inequality.

Comment: I guess the point is that stating an implication between statements with known truth values is useless (so feels "wrong" to say), but as long as the truth values are currently unknown the implication seems useful.

Comment: @StevenGubkin: You are of course right. I don't think we disagree that much on the topic - we might just have a somewhat different focus. And I think it might indeed be a good idea to explain implications by discussing different types of examples where the truth values of the antecedent and consequent are not known - with the case where the propositions depend on a variable being one prominent special case.

Comment: Jochen's answer complements my three comments under Dan's "question", as does [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4674776/21813) that I just posted at mathematics.SE.

Answer (score 2):

I personally think all of these real world examples do a pretty poor job of helping students form an understanding of implication which is both accurate and useful in forming arguments.

For instance,

- False implies False "If the moon is made of cheese, then I am the Pope".
- False implies True "If the moon is made of cheese, then the moon is not made of cheese".
- True implies True "If 1 + 1 = 2, then in nineteen ninety eight the Undertaker threw Mankind off hеll in a cell and he plummeted sixteen feet through an announcer's table."

These all highlight the fundamental lack of "relevance" between the  antecedent and consequent of an implication.  There have been attempts to fix this such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relevance_logic.

Since these kinds of examples are just as "valid" as the more "sensible" ones you are coming up with using rain and clouds, they must also be accepted by the student for them to have a truly robust model of material implication.

My own hot take is to introduce introduction and elimination rules without mentioning the truth table.  These rules are motivated by the following interpretation:

> Interpretation: The implication $p \implies q$ is true exactly when given a proof of $p$, we can produce a proof of $q$.

> Introduction rule:  to argue that $p \implies q$ is true assume we have a proof of $p$ and argue $q$ relative to that assumption.

> Elimination rule:  A proof of $p$ and a proof of $p \implies q$ together constitute a proof of $q$.

These are the things which are useful for actually doing and using mathematics.  The truth table is really not.  It is a distraction.

I would focus on using and proving sensible mathematical implications for a long time before discussing truth tables.  Things like "For all integers x, if 15 divides x then 5 divides x".

I would also **define** absurdity by $\bot \implies p$ for all statements $p$.  This definitely requires some motivation (such as $1=0$ implying both other absurd statements like $2=0$ as well as true statements like $0=0$:  the proof of the first is to multiply both sides by 2 and the second by 0).

You can also mention that this definition of absurdity permits a *uniform* treatment of the proof of quantified implications.  For instance in the proof of "For all integers x, if 15 divides x then 5 divides x" we take an arbitrary integer $x$ and then argue that $5$ divides $x$ under the *assumption* that we have a proof of $15$ dividing $x$.  If $x  = 45$ this proof will do a beautiful job of showing exactly how to take the proof that 15 divides 45 (namely demonstrating that for $k=3$ we have $45 = 15k$) and turning it into a proof that $5$ divides $x$ (namely $ j= 3k = 9$ will work to show that $45 = 5j$).  However if $x = 17$, and we still want "the same argument to work" we need to accept that a false premise can lead to the conclusion we desire.

After getting a lot of experience proving honest mathematical theorems using the introduction and elimination rules I would introduce truth tables as a kind of "algebraic shadow" of our reasoning processes.  It is an arithmetic of truth, but does not fully capture the subtleties.

Then the rows of the truth table become fairly intuititive:  $\bot$ implies everything, if a statement is "true" then it ``proves itself'', so a valid proof of $q$ starting from an assumption of $p$ is to just state $q$, and it should be evident that there is no valid way to argue a false conclusion from a true premise.

I also think that relying on excluded middle as heavily as you do in your proof is a mistake.  I try to avoid excluded middle whenever possible, and I would certainly not want to wed it to my fundamental understanding and motivation for implication.

Comment: For sound pedagogical reasons, truth tables and the equivalence (A => B) <=> ~(A & ~B) are often used to define logical implication in introductory texts. It seems to me that their formal justification using formal rules of introduction and elimination are usually far beyond the scope of such texts and the abilities or motivation of many students. I myself used these "definitions" for many years before realizing they could be derived from "first principles." Also, I see nothing wrong with relying on proofs by contradiction. I know of no good reason to avoid them.

Comment: If you are interested in formally deriving these "definitions" from first principles, see https://dcproof.wordpress.com/2017/12/28/if-pigs-could-fly/

Comment: @DanChristensen We certainly have very different "taste" in logic, which is fine.  For my, I would hate to prove that $15$ divides $x$ implies $5$ divides $x$ by showing that assuming $15$ divides $x$ and $5$ does not divide $x$ leads to a contradiction.  It would be much more natural to proceed "directly".

Comment: I avoid proof by contradiction for many reasons, but chief among them is that it destroys the constructive character of the proof.  I *can* prove that there is an irrational real number by showing that assuming there is not leads to a contradiction (namely that the reals would be countable).  I think this proof is much less informative than just directly demonstrating an irrational number such as $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Just curious... Would you penalize a student for submitting a proof by contradiction in a introductory course on, say, real analysis?

Comment: @DanChristensen No, would not penalize!  Would definitely point out when it is being "overused" however.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the whole example of "It's raining, which means the ground gets wet.", because:

- It might rain but the ground is covered, so it doesn't get wet.
- The ground gets wet, even when it's not raining, because you spilled a glass of water on it.
- ...

Therefore you might better give an example which is less doubtful, like:

> I am located inside this classroom, so I am located inside this school building.

As there is no way being inside the classroom without being at school grounds, this is much clearer.

If somebody says "*But I can still be on school grounds without being inside this classroom*", then you can react that this is a perfect example of $A \Longrightarrow B$ without $B \Longrightarrow A$.

In top of that, this example show a link between logic and set theory, which might be useful at later ages.

Comment: Also a good example because there is no suggestion of causality. And both antecedent and consequent are in the present tense.

Comment: If we are insisting on sticking merely to incidental truth/implications rather than analytic implications, then those `moon is made of cheese` and `circles are round` examples straightforwardly show that `⟹` does not *fundamentally* indicate influence/causality/prophecy, but rather, is essentially a truth-table-row-matching logic gate that sometimes happens to coincide with causation.  And once we are willing to actually consider analytic implications, then that `⟹` is a reasoning relation becomes more evident.

Comment: @ryang Have such "analytic implications" as you call them been shown to be useful in applications?

Comment: @DanChristensen Do mathematical theorems have applications?

Comment: @ryang Yes. "2+2=4," for example, is a theorem with many applications. It is a theorem in the sense that it can be derived from axioms using the rules of classical logic.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question to be about the efficacy of replacing the language "A implies B" with "not A or B." In other words, is there benefit in teaching to avoiding $A\rightarrow B$ and reflexively converting to the conjunctive normal form $\neg A\vee B$? The reasoning goes that "implication" carries too much experiential baggage by intelligent agents such as students, and humans get mired in "causation versus correlation" and other matters irrelevant to logic.

I am trained as a mathematician, and only recently learned how people in artificial intelligence make fundamental use of what they call "proof by resolution" in the context of logical agents. See, for example, chapter 7 of [*Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_Intelligence:_A_Modern_Approach), fourth edition by Russell and Norvig. They start with a knowledge base $KB$, tantamount to a set of axioms in propositional logic or first-order logic, and convert everything to conjunctive normal form. Then to decide if a statement $\alpha$ is entailed by $KB$, in symbols $KB\models\alpha$, one adds $\neg\alpha$ to $KB$ and applies proof by resolution, which amounts to nothing more than algebraic cancellations. For example, if $KB=\lbrace A,A\rightarrow B\rbrace$, the conjunctive normal form is $\lbrace A,\neg A\vee B\rbrace$. If we want to decide if $B$ is entailed by $KB$, we work with $\lbrace A,\neg A\vee B,\neg B\rbrace$.  The we crank the gears of proof by resolution, which in this simple-minded case amounts to "algebraically" canceling $A,\neg A$, and then in the next step algebraically cancelling $B,\neg B$ leaving "absurdity" or $\bot$.

The perspective of working exclusively with conjunctive normal forms, setting up a query $\alpha$ as a proof by contradiction (add $\neg \alpha$), and then going through algebraic cancellations of appearances of $x,\neg x$ is something that is amenable to artificially intelligent agents, who probably have no experiential baggage related to the implication, causation vs correlation, etc. A student is somewhere between an artificially intelligent agent and the "expert system" human teacher.